# Let $f:\mathbb R\xrightarrow{\text{continuous}}\mathbb R$ be s.t. $f(x)=f(\lfloor x\rfloor),\forall x\in\mathbb R.$ Then...

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function and is such
> that $f(x)=f(\lfloor x\rfloor),\forall x\in\mathbb R.$ Then show that
> $f$ is a constant function on $\mathbb R.$

**My attempt:**

Since $\lfloor x\rfloor\in\mathbb Z,$ so $f(\mathbb R)\subseteq f(\mathbb Z)$ (correct, right?). Now $\mathbb Z$ being countable, $f(\mathbb Z)$ must be countable (i.e., countably infinite or finite). But, $f$ being a continuous function, $f(\mathbb R)$ must be a connected set in $\mathbb R.$ Therefore, $f(\mathbb R)$ must be a singleton set whence the result follows immediately.

Is it a valid argument? If not, how do I prove it?

Comment: The argument is valid. You can even say, right off the bat, that $f(\Bbb R)=f(\Bbb Z)$. I’d have argued like this: $f([0,1))=\{c\}$ for some $c$. $f(1)\neq c$ would violate continuity (a few different ways to argue this). Thus $f(1)=c,f([1,2))=\{c\}$. You inductively get $f(\Bbb R)=\{c\}$. Your proof is probably cleaner!

Comment: @FShrike noob here: Just want to make sure my understanding is correct: You're saying that this function would necessarily be some constant, since f([0,1)) is a straight line due to the floor property, and f(1) has to be the same constant to preserve continuity?

Comment: @FShrike yes, will you please elaborate on why we can directly say that $f([0,1))=\{c\}$?

Comment: @thejonymyster Yes, exactly. If $f(1)$ did not sit on this line, the function would fail to be continuous. Either because the intermediate value theorem would fail, or because $f(1)\neq\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=c$.

Comment: @Usual_Learner Let $c=f(0)$. For $0\le x<1$, $\lfloor x\rfloor=0$ so $f(x)=f(0)=c$. Then $f([0,1))=\{c\}$.

Comment: Is this for a course in real analysis, or in topology? The reason I ask is because, at least in the U.S., appealing to the fact that a continuous function maps connected sets to connected sets would not typically be a manner of argumentation used in a real analysis class---more so a topology class.

Comment: Since the range is connected it is an interval and a non empty interval is either uncountable or has a single point.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Sir, actually I am familiar with the elementary definitions of both of these courses. So, I used "connected set in $\mathbb R$" instead of saying "an interval" simply. But, my concepts are a bit shaky, to be honest. Trying to improve!

Comment: @FShrike Thank you, sir, understood...

Comment: @copper.hat Sir, that reminds me of the empty set $\emptyset$ which can be expressed as $(+\infty,-\infty),$ and does not contain any point!